# COUNT(*) FILTER (WHERE... In BigQuery

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

How can I filter in a count in BigQuery?

In Postgres I was doing something like:

```
COUNT(*) FILTER (WHERE event_date>('{{ report_date }}'::date-INTERVAL '2 WEEK'))
```

Though this does not work in BigQuery. What't the best alternative? I use standard SQL.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

For BigQuery Standard SQL, you can use [COUNTIF](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/functions-and-operators#countif) and [DATE_SUB](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/standard-sql/functions-and-operators#date_sub) functions as below

```sql
COUNTIF(event_date > DATE_SUB(CURRENT_DATE(), INTERVAL 2 WEEK))
```

You can test / play with above using below dummy example

```sql
#standardSQL
WITH `project.dataset.yourTable` AS (
  SELECT 1 AS event_id, DATE '2017-11-19' AS event_date UNION ALL
  SELECT 2, DATE '2017-11-18' UNION ALL
  SELECT 3, DATE '2017-10-15' 
)
SELECT 
  COUNT(*) AS all_events,
  COUNTIF(event_date > DATE_SUB(CURRENT_DATE(), INTERVAL 2 WEEK)) AS qualified_events 
FROM `project.dataset.yourTable`
```

The output as one would expect is

```sql
all_events  qualified_events     
3           2
```

Answer (score 8):

Use `case`:

```
SUM(CASE WHEN event_date > '{{ report_date }}'::date-INTERVAL '2 WEEK' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END)
```

This is the "old-fashioned" way, before Postgres implemented the ANSI standard `FILTER` syntax.